# How to improve my listening skill?

Tags: listening

I'm a developer, I want to use English to communicate with customers, but I don't speak fluently and with confidence, and my listening skill is very bad. I want to improve my listening skill, I've tried some ways such as: voa special English, 365 crazy, ... however, it seems they are not good for me. Please share your experience, tips to improve my English listening. Thanks so much!

Comment: Listen a lot, with and without English subtitles.  Try listening to something *with* English subs repeatedly until you can follow along, then try the same material *without* subs until you can follow by ear.  Practice every day; persistence is the most important part of ear training.  Your mind needs to develop its ability to identify and distinguish the sounds of English, and for that it needs time and practice.

Comment: What snailplane said. You might also want to check out some of my related posts: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14584/3281, http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14824/3281, http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14343/3281.

Comment: Thanks @snailplane so much. Maybe, I need to improve my persistence before improve my english :)

Comment: It's a bit counterintuitive, but conversational speaking practice will also help with listening. Audio lessons involving hearing and repeating (then later engaging in) English conversations will improve your aural discrimination, because you'll be paying close attention to differences in the sounds between the material and your pronunciation.

Comment: I would like to share my experience used right now. Read transcripts of news then adjust the way you pronounce. Listen to your own voice and be familiar with it.Compare it with what anchors say. You kind of improve your speaking skill but actually you improve your listening skill as well. How fantastic it is! You kill two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to improve your listening is media. I say this because, by listening to English news, watching English movies and listening to English music, you can improve your listening skills without taking much time out of your life. This way is both enjoyable and effective and because you are using time that you would consume media anyway, it is time-efficient.

Comment: Good idea: _"This way is both enjoyable and effective"_

Comment: It is highly effective and I personally know many of my friends who have greatly improved their listening and overall English by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

When someone's speaking to you, look at their eyes; don't gaze around. It will make you focus on the speaker and not hear the noises around you. You can practice by listening to quick speakers, like TV broadcasters, or ones in real life. In real life, you can chat with them and for whatever you don't hear clearly, ask them what they said.

Additional help:

If you are not interested in the topic of conversation and don't want to listen, you can look at the speaker's nose. It will seem like you are listening and respectful, even though you might be thinking about other things.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question - this answer is about _looking_ like you're listening, rather than actually improving aural comprehension skill, which is what the OP was really asking about. (If it isn't what they were asking about, then it's off-topic for ELL.)

Comment: Meeting someone's eyes consistently isn't always a good idea socially speaking.  Watching someone's lips can be helpful while listening, by the way—our brains can integrate this sort of information into what we hear.